# Is there any easy way in DolphinDB to accomplish what the **shift down** function does in Python?

Tags: python, shift, dolphindb

Is there any easy way in DolphinDB to accomplish what the **shift down** function does in Python?

Say I have a matrix that is 3x3:

```
#0 #1 #2
-- -- --
1  4  7 
2  5  8 
3  6  9
```

I want to shift one row down in a matrix as follow:

```
#0 #1 #2
-- -- --
        
1  4  7 
2  5  8
```

How can this be done in DolphinDB?
Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

Well the `LAG` analytic function sort of does this.  Assuming you just want to *view* your data this way, and that the first column provides the ordering, you could use:

```sql
SELECT
    LAG(col1) OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS col1,
    LAG(col2) OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS col2,
    LAG(col3) OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS col3
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
m=1..9$3:3
prev(m)
```

or

```
each(move{,1},m)
```